# How do I load a X509 Certificate Request in PHP?

Tags: php, certificate, openssl

openssl_csr_export is able to take a request and export it as a string, but where is the opposite function which takes in the request and returns the resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [phpseclib a pure PHP CSR encoder / decoder](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/):

```
<?php
include('File/X509.php');

$x509 = new File_X509();
print_r($x509->loadCSR('...'));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do the opposite and there really shouldn't be any need to do it anyway - all you can do with a CSR resource is either to sign it or export it but no editing.

To sign a CSR you can use the exported string value, no need to use CSR resource for that.

Comment: How would I check that the string that I'm signing is what I think it is and hasn't somehow been modified?

Comment: If you want to use `openssl_csr_get_subject` to get the request information or the public key with `openssl_csr_get_public_key` to validate the file, then you can use string CSR as the value for these functions, no need to use CSR resource object. There really aren't anything you can do with a resource you can't do with the string value.